# Callable function C++

Tags: c++, callable

I've read various answer on SO and still didn't understood how I should make an object method to be callable in this case:

Considering:

```
     Class A
{
       void generator(void)
       {
            int i = 1;
            while(1)
            {
                if(i == 1)
                {
                    one(/***/);//Should be a flag 
                    i = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                     two(/**/);//Should be a flag 
                     i = 1;
                }
          }
      }
      template <typename CallbackFunction>
      void one(CallbackFunction&& func)
      {

      }
      template <typename CallbackFunction>
      void two(CallbackFunction&& func)
      {

      }

      A()
      {
          std::thread t(&A::generator, this);
          t.detach();
      }
};
```

and a simple main file:

```
void pOne(/**/)
{
    std::cout<<"1"<<std::endl;
}

void pTwo(/**/)
{
    std::cout<<"2"<<std::endl;
}

 A myA;
 A.One(pOne);
 A.Two(pTwo);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

   while(1){}

}
```

Here are where I'm at:

generator() should update a flag, and both one() & two() should poll on that flag & loop forever.

One() (two() also) should have a function pointer as parameters and if necessary other parameters, pOne() should have the same parameters except the function pointer.

So my questions are:

1) Is my understanding correct?

2) Is there a clean way to make generator() to start one() or two() ? (flags, semaphore, mutex, or anything that is a standard way to do it)

3) Assuming that the code was working, is it behaving as I expect ? i.e. printing 1 and 2?

*if it matters, I'm on ubuntu*

Comment: There are some typos in your code, and this would be much clearer as a smaller [mcve]. Otherwise, I'm not really sure what you're asking. Assuming the code is working? Is it not already? What are you asking? Why don't you just run this and test it yourself?

Comment: Because its not running, Have no idea how to define both one() & two() and how to make generator() to start one's & two's callbacks

Comment: But you're not asking how to get it running, or putting compiler errors or what you tried. You're asking hypothetically if it worked would it do what you want. Perhaps you should [edit] your post to clarify what is it that's your problem (e.g. you're trying to have a thread print 1 and 2 interchangeably, or you're trying to have two different functions called by the thread, but the thread doesn't know what the functions are ahead of time or whatever it is you're trying to do)

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? The code you posted has many flaws design-wise and if you explain what is the purpose of what you want to accomplish it will be easier to understand your question and to give you a good answer

Comment: Some questions in mind: why do you need a class ? It doesn't look like you are holding any state in it (except the functions) and you are also not taking care of the thread so you can just make a thread in main. Also why do you call a function that takes a function as input? Are you implementing some dispatch mechanism? You are most likely trying to create something common that you can find some form of implemention online, so please refine your question

Comment: Question is actually not that unclear, he is asking 2 questions using the wrong words: 1) how to create a callback function, 2) how to create an event handler, his generator is actually an event "generator" that should raised event for One()/Two()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer 1: Like everyone else, I'm interpreting the question as:

-> You need an event handler

-> You want callback methods on those events

And the only reason I think that is because I helped you on a i2c handler sequence before.

Also, there are better logic than this, its provided following your stubs "rules".

You mentioned that you are on Ubuntu, so you will be lacking windows event system.

Disclaimer 2:

1- To avoid going to deep I'm going to use a simple way to handle events.

2- Code is untested & provided for logic only

```
class Handler
{

private:

    std::mutex event_one;
    event_one.lock();

    void stubEventGenerator(void)
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            if(!event_one.try_lock())
            {
                event_one.unlock();
            }

            sleep(15); //you had a sleep so I added one
        }
    }

    template <typename CallbackFunction>
    void One__(CallbackFunction && func)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            event_one.lock();
            func();

        }
    }
public:

    Handler()
    {
        std::thread H(&Handler::stubEventGenerator, this);
    }

    ~Handler()
    {
        //clean threads, etc
        //this should really have a quit handler
    }

    template <typename CallbackFunction>
    void One(CallbackFunction && func) //I think you have it right, still I'm not 100% sure
    {
        std::thread One_thread(&Handler::One__, this, func); //same here
    }


};
```

Some points:

One() as to be a wrapper for the thread calling One__() if you want it to be non-blocking.

mutex can be a simple way to handle events as long as the same event doesn't occur during its previous occurence (you are free to use a better/more suitable tool for your use case, or use boost:: *only* if necessary)

Prototype of One() & One__() are probably wrong, that's some research for you.

Finally: How it works:

std::mutex.lock() is blocking as long as it can't lock the mutex, thus One__ will wait as long as your event generator won't unlock it.

Once unlock One__ will execute your std::function & wait for the event (mutex) to be raised (unlock) again.

*far from a perfect answer, but lack of time, and not being able to put that in a comment made me post it, will edit later*

Answer (score -1):

With whatever limited information you provided this code can be made compilable in following manner:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
typedef void(*fptr)();
void pOne(/**/)
{
    std::cout<<"1"<<std::endl;
}

void pTwo(/**/)
{
    std::cout<<"2"<<std::endl;
}
class A
{
    public:
       void generator(void)
       {
            int i = 1;
            while(1)
            {
                if(i == 1)
                {
                    fptr func = pOne;
                    one(func);//Should be a flag 
                    i = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                     fptr func = pTwo;
                     two(func);//Should be a flag 
                     i = 1;
                }
          }
      }
      template <typename CallbackFunction>
      void one(CallbackFunction&& func)
      {
         func();
      }
      template <typename CallbackFunction>
      void two(CallbackFunction&& func)
      {
        func();
      }

      A()
      {
          std::thread t(&A::generator, this);
          t.detach();
      }
};
int main()
{
  A myA;
  while(1)
  {
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If you want that one and two should accept any type/number of arguments then pass second argument as variadic template.Also I could not understand why you want one and two to be called from main as your generator function is for this purpose only and this generator function is called from thread which is detached in class constructor

Comment: I will elaborate later, but its not at all what the OP is trying to do. His goal is most likely to have class methods that will execute a function passed as parameter when one of the state (1 or 2) occurs. I.e. not something hardcoded. See it as his A.One() is looping forever waiting for a semaphore/flag & then processing the std::function

Comment: Ok but then what is the use of generate function if class methods need to be called from outside

Comment: I will cut my hand if the generate function is not here to produce an event in fact happening in something more complex and set here as a way to raise events that should handle One() and Two()

Comment: Please don't cut your hand just rephrase the question or provide some alternative solution so that everybody else is also enlightened !

Comment: I don't have enough time as its *I think* its a really wide question, but will asap